# Cron job with django application

Tags: python, django, cron, django-cron

I would like to use a `cron` task in order to delete `media files` if the condition is True.

Users generate export files stored in the Media folder. In order to clean export files in the background, I have a Cron task which loops over each file and looks if the expiry delay is passed or not.

I used `django-cron` library

**Example:**

File in Media Folder : *Final_Products___2019-04-01_17:50:43.487845.xlsx*

My Cron task looks like this :

```
class MyCronExportJob(CronJobBase):
    """ Cron job which removes expired files at 18:30 """
    RUN_AT_TIMES = ['18:30']

    schedule = Schedule(run_at_times=RUN_AT_TIMES)
    code = 'app.export_cron_job'

    def do(self):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        media_folder = os.listdir(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'exports'))
        for files in media_folder:
            file = os.path.splitext(files.split(settings.EXPORT_TITLE_SEPARATOR, 1)[1])[0]
            if datetime.datetime.strptime(file, '%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S.%f') + timedelta(minutes=settings.EXPORT_TOKEN_DELAY) < now:
                os.remove(os.path.join(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'exports'), files))

# settings.EXPORT_TOKEN_DELAY = 60 * 24
```

**I edited my crontab -e :**

```
30 18 * * * source /home/user/Bureau/Projets/app/venv/bin/activate.csh && python /home/user/Bureau/Projets/app/src/manage.py runcrons --force app.cron.MyCronExportJob
```

Then I launched `service cron restart`

But nothing as changed. My file is still there. However, it should be removed because his date is greater than `now + settings.EXPORT_TOKEN_DELAY`

I'm using Ubuntu to local dev and FreeBSD as a production server environment.

**EDIT:**

I tried some things but crontab doesn't work for the moment.

1) `* * * * * /bin/date >> /home/user/Bureau/Projets/app/cron_output`
==> It works, so crontab works

2) I ran : `python manage.py runcrons` in my console
==> It works

3) I ran this script (cron.sh):

```
source /home/user/.bashrc
cd /home/user/Bureau/Projets/app
pyenv activate app

python src/manage.py runcrons --force

deactivate
```

==> It works

4) I ran this crontab line :

```
35 10 * * * /home/user/Bureau/Projets/app/utility/cron.sh
```

==> Service restarted at 10h32, I waited until 10h38 : nothing !

Comment: This job will run at 6:30 pm once per day.  When did you restart your cron service?

Comment: Note you shouldn't need to activate the virtualenv in the crontab - just use the python in the virtualenv, e.g. `30 18 * * * /path/to/virtualenv/bin/python manage.py runcrons --force app.cron.MyCronExportJob`. Or add `/path/to/virtualenv/bin/` to `PATH` at the top of the crontab, then use `30 18 * * * python manage.py runcrons --force app.cron.MyCronExportJob`.

Comment: @JohnGordon As I'm testing in local, at 18:25 for example I configure cron.py file + crontab -e to 18:30 and I launch immediately `service cron restart`.

Comment: And at 18:31 nothing has changed?

Comment: @JohnGordon Nothing at 18:31

Comment: @Alasdair I tried to write my cron like this : `30 18 * * * /home/my_name/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/envs/app/bin/python manage.py runcrons --force app.cron.MyCronExportJob` but nothing has changed.

Comment: Yes, that was just a suggestion to simplify the cron command, it wasn't meant to fix the issue.

Comment: Are you sure your machine is using your local timezone and not UTC?

Comment: How I can check that ? In django settings I have : USE_TZ = False
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Paris'

Comment: Those are the Django settings - run `date` to check the sytem's time and timezone. If it's on UTC, the you'll see something like `Thu 11 Apr 17:02:47 UTC 2019`, and your 18:30 cron job should run in about an hour and a half.

Comment: As a first step in debugging this problem, add some print messages to the `do()` function.  Put one at the very top of the function to confirm that it runs, and also one at the top of every loop and if/else statement, so you know exactly what path the code is following.

Comment: @Alasdair date gives me the exact datetime. For example date launched at 09:19 gives me `vendredi 12 avril 2019, 09:18:35 (UTC+0200)`.

Comment: @JohnGordon I will try to do that and see if I can print. But How I can see if the issue is not the cron system himself ?

Comment: That's why I suggested the print message at the very top of the function, so you can verify that the code is executed via cron.